# Restrictions on the time derivative of signed distance functions?

Tags: general-topology, derivatives, analytic-geometry

I've been thinking about solids (or 2d or n-dimensional objects) defined as [SDFs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_distance_function). If I have an SDF that changes continuously (while remaining a valid SDF) over some additional non-spatial variable (like "time"), what properties of its derivative in respect to that variable can I deduce? I'm interested in anything that seems interesting to you.

---

(I should clarify what I need this for: I think it would be interesting to have a continuously changing solid (defined as an SDF) controlled by an AI (that would take the current state of the SDF as an input and output the time derivative), but before I do anything I need to figure out how I would sanitize the output of such an AI.)